# Backbone.js - A "url" property or function must be specified

Tags: javascript, backbone.js

I read all the topics on here about the argument but I can't understand what's with this code, is some hours I'm trying to get a sense of it:

It says "Uncaught Error: A "url" property or function must be specified" when I fire events save and remove from the TranslationView.
I tried to figure out other codes but even adding explicitly the url property to the collection it doesn't work... Thank You in advance

```
  /**
 * Translation Collection - The document
 * -- Collection of all translations in a document
 */
var Document = Backbone.Collection.extend({
        model: Translation,
        localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("translations-db")    
    });
var Docs = new Document;

/**
 * Translation View
 * -- A single language version
 * This is a version of translation
 */

var TranslationView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: _.template('<div class="cnt-translation"><span class="delete-btn">delete</span><span class="save-btn">save</span> Language: <input value="english" /><textarea id="translation_0" class="translation"></textarea></div>'),

    events: { 
      'click span.delete-btn': 'remove',
      'click span.save-btn': 'save'
    },
      //'chnage ul#main-menu #add': 'addText'

    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 'render', 'unrender', 'remove','save'); 
      this.listenTo(this.model, 'destroy', this.remove);
    },

    render: function(counter){
      this.$el.html(this.template(this.model.toJSON()));    
      return this;
    },

    unrender: function(){
      $(this.el).remove();
    },

    remove: function(){
      console.log(this.model);
      this.model.destroy();
    },

    save: function(){
      console.log(this.model);
      this.model.save();
      console.log(localStorage);

    }

});


/**
* Translation Main View
* -- The Application
* This is the top level piece of the app
*/

var AppView = Backbone.View.extend({
    el: $('#application'),
    type: 'localStorage', // in future also "remoteStorage"

    events: {
      'click #add_trans': 'createOnEnter',
      'click #save_trans': 'saveTranslations',
      'click #remove_trans': 'removeTranslation'
    },

    initialize: function(){
      _.bindAll(this, 
        'render',
        'saveTranslations',
        'addTranslation'
      ); 
      this.listenTo(Docs, 'add', this.addTranslation);
      this.listenTo(Docs, 'all', this.render);
      this.listenTo(Docs, 'reset', this.reloadAll);
      this.render();
      console.log('initialized and texts loaded');
      Docs.fetch();
    },
    ....

    render: function(){  
      var self = this;
      /*
      _(this.collection.models).each(function(translation){ 
        self.appendTranslation(translation);
      }, this);
      */
    }

    addTranslation: function(){
      console.log('addTrans called');
      var translation = new Translation();
      translation.set({
        id: 'translation_' + Docs.length,
        language: 'english' // modify item defaults
      });
      var translationView = new TranslationView({ model: translation });
      $(this.el).append(translationView.render().el);
      console.log(Docs);
    },

    createOnEnter: function(e) {
      Docs.create({title: 'new trans'});
    }


}); 


var ENTER_KEY = 13;    
var app = new AppView();
console.log(app);
})(jQuery);
```

Comment: This is too much code. I suggest you debug it some to narrow down where the error is originating.

Comment: I removed some parts, but I think that it can't be less, since I don't know where really the error can be, all I know is that it starts from the remove or save method, and the error can be located in some parts here.. or just help me to remove some code maybe. Can you?

Comment: Your `Backbone collection` should have a `url: "/translations"`. That didn't work for you?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that you try to save/destroy a model object which was never associated to your local storage backed collection.

The local-storage plugin first looks for the `localStorage` property on the model if it finds none it looks on the model's collection for the `localStorage` if still no `localStorage` found it fallbacks to the default `Backbone.Sync` behaior which needs an `url` so you get the exception.

And you have an unassisted model object because you create one in your `addTranslation`:

```
var translationView = new TranslationView({ model: translation });
```

But you don't need to this because this method called when an item added to your collection and you get the newly added item as a parameter.

You just need to change your method use the parameter `translation` instead of creating a new one.

```
addTranslation: function(translation){
    translation.set({
        id: 'translation_' + Docs.length,
        language: 'english' // modify item defaults
    });

    var translationView = new TranslationView({ model: translation });

    $(this.el).append(translationView.render().el);
},
```

Comment: Thank you, was precisely that! One day I need to dig deeper into backbone's source.. do you know some article where is shown in detail how backbone works inside? I think that docs lack a bit..

Comment: @Novalink I'm always using the annotated source code of Backbone: http://backbonejs.org/docs/backbone.html